# Self extract ZIP that can run a command

Tags: shell, package-management

I have:

- install.sh
- config/*
- images/*
- etc

I would like to bundle all that up in 1 file, so that when the user runs that file (no args), it will:

1. self extract in /tmp/[temp_name]/
2. run /tmp/[temp_name]/install.sh

Doable?

Scope is unix and/or windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any self extracting archive will do, of the type typically used to install software.

For example, [makeself.sh](https://makeself.io/) is notable for its portablity. It runs on several UNIXes and has a startup script feature.